# Import a SASS file without the imports of this file

Tags: sass

I'm trying to make a lot of small libraries.
They are all imporing the "import.scss" file.
So they are compiling like this :

```
/Import
    Import.scss
/Lib1
    Lib1.scss
    Lib1.min.css
/Lib2
    Lib2.scss
    Lib2.min.css
```

So that's cool.
But what I need now is to make a `all.lib.min.css`.
So I made an `all.lib.scss` ayt the root of the SASS folder, and I imported all of my small libs.
The problem is : Because of the multiple imports of the `Import.scss` file, the content of this file is replicate a lot of times.

Is there a way to say in my `all.lib.scss` to import without importing inner imported files ? Or any other way to do that ?

Comment: If you don't need the lib1, lib2 to be a standalon, don't import the `Import.scss` at all, only include it in the all.lib file

Comment: Thanks, @ItayGal, but I also need them to be a standalon :/ Like a Bootstrap lib, I need to allow users to download all of my libs in one, and a distinct lib if he just need one of them.